# Function won't read from two typeclasses

Tags: haskell

I declared a class and two instances:

```
class A a where
  name :: a -> String
  dMs :: a -> [(String,String,Double)]

instance A B where
  name s = B s
  dMs a = dM a

instance A C where
  name s = C s
  dMs a = dM a

dM :: (A a) => [a] -> [(String,String,Double)]
```

But when I compile my with the header above I get an error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘[a0]’ with actual type ‘C’
    In the first argument of ‘dM’, namely ‘a’
    In the expression: dM a
```

I want the `dM` function to be able to take a list of types `B` or `C`.

If I change the header to accept just one type (either just `B` or just `C`) the code compiles and works without a glitch.

Comment: Where have you defined `B` and `C` ?

Comment: @Sibi Earlier in the code. Each is a `Data` with name, and some other relevant values. They each work individually.

Comment: Try to define dM directly in your typeclass as a default implementation. At the moment, you're trying to use the instance of B/C, inside the definition of the instance itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working now.

```
class A a where
  name :: a -> String
  dMs :: [a] -> [(String,String,Double)]

instance A B where
  name s = B s
  dMs a = dM a

instance A C where
  name s = C s
  dMs a = dM a

dM :: (A a) => [a] -> [(String,String,Double)]
```

So what did it was specifying in `Class` that it should take a list of `a`, like this: `[a]`.

Thanks for the help everyone.